Can 時 be used as a counter to mean '(school) period'?
While reading a teaching guide for 4th grade mathematics, I came across the following sentence:
本単元では、第2 時で学習する平行に着目して色々な四角形を弁別していく。
I understand that 第２時 refers to 'the second hour', but in this context does it simply mean 'the second period (of teaching)'? Is a period in Japanese primary school a full hour, and if so, is that why they are using this counter? I was expecting a counter with 期 in some way.

At schools, I've seen 時間, 校時, and 時限, but nothing with 期.

Interesting, thank you. Would 時 make sense here as a 'period' then?

Is a period in Japanese primary school a full hour -- Normally it's 45 minutes.

Ok, then I am not sure why the counter 時 is being used here.

With breaks factored in, each class still does occupy roughly an hour of the school day.

Generally, the units used to count lectures or classes in schools are 時間, 時限, 限, and 講.

N時間目: Used mainly in elementary schools or informal conversations. Although a single class may be 45 minutes or 80 minutes long, the term 時間 is commonly used without issue (as long as 目 is attached).
N時限(目): Used mainly in higher education.
N限: Primarily used colloquially by university students.
第N講: Sometimes used in serious, lecture-style textbooks in place of 第N章.

第N時 is rare in both spoken and written Japanese. It appears to be used in the same way as 第N講, but it's not a nationally shared practice. 第N時 could be a custom specific to certain universities, but I'm not sure.
第N期 is basically "N-th season", which is far larger than above. 第N期 is used for events that repeat in cycles of at least two weeks, or as long as a year.

I am going to assume 時 here is a shorter 時間 more simply then, thank you.

大学で時間割の話で「2講時」とか「2講時目」とか、書いてあったり、言ったりするんですけど、関西だけですかね（関西では大学生は「2年生」でなく「2回生」って言うけど、関東ではそんなの言わないって聞きますし）。ほんで、１講時が２時間分(45分×2で一コマ)っていうややこしい…

@chocolate 個人的に「2講時」は初耳で、「2回生」は聞いたことがあるかな程度です。

うわ～やっぱり「講時」は使わないのね・・・漢字変換の候補がめっちゃ下にあるからおかしいと思ったしくしく
